# How to parse each row of an excel using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-adf

here is my requirement:

1. I have an excel with few columns in it and few rows with data
2. I have uploaded this excel in Azure blob storage
3. Using ADF I need to read this excel and parse the records in it one by one and perform an action of creating dynamic folders in Azure blob.
4. This needs to be done for each and every record present in the excel.
5. Each record in the excel has some information that is going to help me create the folders dynamically.

Could someone help me in choosing the right set of activities or data flow in ADF to do this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is my Excel file as a Source.

[image]

I have created folders in Blob storage based on **Country** column.
I have selected DataFlow activity.

[image]

As shown in below screenshot, Go to **Optimize** tab of **Sink configuration**.

Now select `Partition option` as `Set Partition`.

`Partition type` as `Key`.

And `Unique value per partition` as `Country` column.

Now run Pipeline.

[image]

**Expected Output:-**

[image]

Inside these folders you will get files with corresponding data.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Is there a way to create these country folders in the blob dynamically? For eg. when Row 1 is processed the Folder for India is created and so on.